# Getting an TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable for line number 4

Tags: python, for-loop, int, iteration

```
   for i in range(122):     
       if i <= 121:         
           for j in range(6):             
               consumption = consumption + df2.loc[df2['Main Load [kWh]']]     
               pos = pos + 1         
            weekly_consumption=weekly_consumption.append(pos,consumption)         
            consumption = 0    
       else:        
           for j in range(1):             
               consumption = consumption + df2.loc[df2['Main Load [kWh]']]             
               pos = pos + 1         
           weekly_consumption=weekly_consumption.append(pos,consumption)         
           consumption = 0
```

Comment: `for i in 122`?  Maybe `for i in range(122)`?

Comment: What is the point of `pandas` tag in this question?

Comment: @ScottBoston thanks, it is working!
 in line number 4 , getting error : 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: What's your line #4 now? Did you change anything? Post the updated code?

Comment: for i in range(122):
    if i <= 121:
        for j in range(6):
            consumption = consumption + df2.iloc[df2['Main Load [kWh]']]
            pos = pos + 1
        weekly_consumption=weekly_consumption.append(pos,consumption)
        consumption = 0
    else:
        for j in range(1):
            consumption = consumption + df2.iloc[df2['Main Load [kWh]']]
            pos = pos + 1
        weekly_consumption=weekly_consumption.append(pos,consumption)
        consumption = 0
Error:IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds

Comment: @ak_app i just updated with i in range(122) and the error is in the usage of .iloc

if i use .loc the error is - 'NoneType' object is not iterable 
for .iloc the error is IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds

Comment: You should just not update for one loop but do it for all the for loops where you are trying to iterate on numbers. Also, instead of posting code here in comment change your original post with the latest one and what you have tried.

Comment: @ak_app updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't iterate on numbers but on collections. You can try on a range of numbers, like

```
for i in range(122):
```

or on a list, string etc. like

```
for i in '122':
```